# Python: How do I use a function to return a dictionary from an arbitrary number of lists/arrays?

Tags: python

Basically (as an MWE), I'm looking to write a function that behaves as follows:

```
def my_function(*args):
    value_dict = {}
    for arg in args:
        #do some math on arg to create variable
        value_dict.update("arg_name" = arg_variable)
    return value_dict
```

...but I'm having issues writing code to produce a string for arg_name. Ideally the keys would be strings containing the array names, although I appreciate that's not a particularly wise idea.

Comment: Can you spec this function? How should it behave from the user's perspective?

Answer (score 0):

`value_dict[arg_name] = arg_variable` and you need also to produce arg_name somehow, or I really didn't understand question.

Ok, if you want `dict` as input do:

```
def my_function(**kwargs):
    value_dict = {}
    for arg in kwargs.iteritems():
        print arg

my_function(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

Comment: The issue is getting something to produce arg_name in the absence of there being a sort of getvariablename(arg) function that outputs a string.

Comment: @user3046460 *args is just a list, no names there

Comment: No such thing as `getvariablename(arg)`. Variables and objects are separate, and objects don't have names

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but surely there's some trivial way of getting function(array1, array2, array3) to output {"array1": 5, "array2": 6, "array3": 10} sort of thing?

Comment: @user3046460 I doubt you understand the whole concept of parameters passing in Python. There are two distinct things: arguments names and the actual variable values passed to the function. There is no way to get the second from the function. If you define function with argument `*args` there is no way to get parameters names. The best you can is something like this `def my_function(array1, array2, array3):  print my_function.func_code.co_varnames`

Comment: @user3046460 you are trying to solve your task with completely wrong approach and focus on the approach itself instead of reconsidering approach.